# Is there a standard name for embedded loop markers in WAV files?

Tags: wav, sample, sampler, standard

Using any audio editor (I'm using Audition), how do I name loop markers to be recognized by samplers as loops? Can I name them anything (My Happy Loop Begins here / My Happy Loop Ends here), or is there a standardized naming scheme for embedded markers in WAV files?